# Differential equation bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y’=\frac{1}{1+x^2+e^y}$
Prove that any solution of this equation is bounded on $R$
Could you give me a hint about how it should be proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$y'<\frac {1}{1+x^2}$$

Integrating and we get $$ y(x)-y(0)\le \tan ^{-1} x$$

Thus $y(x)$ is bounded.